# Mosquitto Python Paho How can i get all message since last connection

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

I have a python client that posts to a mosquitto broker. This broker is linked to a second broker via a bridge. On deck I wish I have a python script that subscribes to the topic. I would like to be able to retrieve all the messages published between two client connections.

I just have the last message

mosquitto.conf broker

```
pid_file /run/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
log_type all
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S


include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 1883
allow_anonymous true

persistent_client_expiration 14d

connection bridge-rpi
address 192.168.1.140:1884
topic # out 2
cleansession true
remote_clientid xxxx
```

mosquitto.conf bridge

```
listener 1884
allow_anonymous true
persistent_client_expiration 14d
persistence true
persistence_file mosquitto.db
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto
log_type all
log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
log_timestamp true
log_timestamp_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
```

subscribe code :

```
#Configuration MQTT
MQTT_HOST = "localhost"
MQTT_PORT = 1884
MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL = 45
MQTT_TOPIC = "cn"

#Configuration Influxdb
INFLUXDB_ADDRESS = 'localhost'
INFLUXDB_USER = 'xxxx'
INFLUXDB_PASSWORD = 'xxxx'
INFLUXDB_DATABASE = 'xxxx'

influxdb_client = InfluxDBClient(INFLUXDB_ADDRESS, 8086, INFLUXDB_USER, INFLUXDB_PASSWORD,  database=INFLUXDB_DATABASE)


# initialisation du client MQTT
mqttc = mqtt.Client("PythonMqttToInfluxDb")
#mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# connexion au broker MQTT
mqttc.connect(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT, MQTT_KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL)


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    """ The callback for when the client connects to the broker."""
    print("Connecté au serveur MQTT avec le code de retour "+str(rc))

    # Subscribe to a topic
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC,qos=2)

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    """ The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server."""
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))
    sensor_data = _parse_mqtt_message(msg.topic, msg.payload.decode('utf-8'))
    json_body = [
        {
            'measurement': "cn",
            'time': parsedJson["timestamp"],
            'tags': {
                'site': parsedJson["site"],
                'frequence': parsedJson["frequence"],
                'info': parsedJson["timestamp"]
            },
            'fields': {
                'cn': parsedJson["cn"]
                #'time': parsedJson["timestamp"]
            }
        }
    ]
    print(json_body)
    influxdb_client.write_points(json_body, time_precision='n')



## MQTT logic - Register callbacks and start MQTT client

mqttc.on_connect = on_connect
mqttc.on_message = on_message
mqttc.loop_forever()
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that the Clean Session flag is set to false to ensure that queued messages are delivered.

From the paho [doc](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#constructor-reinitialise)

> **Client()**
>
> `Client(client_id="", clean_session=True, userdata=None, protocol=MQTTv311, transport="tcp")`
>
> The Client() constructor takes the following arguments:
>
> - client_id - the unique client id string used when connecting to the broker. If client_id is zero length or None, then one will be randomly
>   generated. In this case the clean_session parameter must be True.
> - clean_session - a boolean that determines the client type. If True, the broker will remove all information about this client when it
>   disconnects. If False, the client is a durable client and subscription
>   information and queued messages will be retained when the client
>   disconnects.
>
>   Note that a client will never discard its own outgoing messages on disconnect. Calling connect() or reconnect() will cause the messages
>   to be resent. Use reinitialise() to reset a client to its original
>   state.
> - userdata - user defined data of any type that is passed as the userdata parameter to callbacks. It may be updated at a later point
>   with the user_data_set() function.
> - protocol - the version of the MQTT protocol to use for this client. Can be either MQTTv31 or MQTTv311 transport
>   set to "websockets" to send MQTT over WebSockets. Leave at the default of "tcp" to use raw TCP.

e.g.

```
# initialisation du client MQTT
mqttc = mqtt.Client(client_id="PythonMqttToInfluxDb", clean_session=False)
```